# PEP 424 __length_hint__() - Is there a way to do the same for generators or zips?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-internals

Just came across this awesome `__length_hint__()` method for iterators from PEP 424 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0424/). Wow! A way to get the iterator length without exhausting the iterator.

My questions:

1. Is there a simple explanation how does this magic work? I'm just curious.
2. Are there limitations and cases where it wouldn't work? ("hint" just sounds a bit suspicious).
3. Is there a way to get the hint for zips and generators as well? Or is it something fundamental only to iterators?

**Edit:** BTW, I see that the `__length__hint__()` counts from current position to the end. i.e. partially consumed iterator will report the remaining length. Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several answers to the question, but they are slightly missing the point: `__length_hint__` is not magic. It is a protocol. If an object does not implement the protocol, that's it.

---

Let's take a detour and look at `a + b`, as it is a simple example. The `+` operator relies on `a.__add__` and `b.__radd__` to actually do something. `int` implements `__add__` to mean *arithmetic* addition (`1 + 2 == 3`), while `list` implements `__add__` to mean content concatenation (`[1] + [2] == [1, 2]`).  This is because `__add__` is just a protocol, to which objects must adhere if they provide it. The definition for `__add__` is basically just "take another operand and return an object".

There is no separate, universal meaning to `+`. If operands do not provide `__add__` or `_radd__`, there is nothing python can do about it.

---

Coming back to the actual question(s), what does this imply?

> Is there a simple explanation how does this magic work? I'm just curious.

All the magic is listed in [PEP 424](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0424/) but it is basically: try `len(obj)`, fall back to `obj.__length_hint__`, use the default. That is **all** the magic.

In practice, an object has to implement `__length_hint__` depending what it knows about itself. For example, take the `range_iterator` of the [range backport](https://github.com/maxfischer2781/backports.range/commit/ea360ce47dfc0826e67ec77096920b36ccef139e) or the [Py3.6 C Code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eade39e57b1427df0ec9dd24bf19aae468d7c066/Objects/rangeobject.c#L767)):

```
return self._stop - self._current
```

Here, the iterator know how long it is at most, and how much it has provided. If it wouldn't keep track of the later, it might still return how long it is at most. In either way, it *must* use internal knowledge about itself.

> Are there limitations and cases where it wouldn't work? ("hint" just sounds a bit suspicious).

Obviously, objects that don't implement `__length_hint__` or `__len__` don't work. Fundamentally, any object that does not have enough knowledge about its state **cannot** implement it.

Chained generators usually do not implement it. For example, `(a ** 2 for a in range(5))` will not forward the length-hint from `range`. This is sensible if you consider that there may be an arbitrary chain of iterators:  `length_hint` is only an optimization for pre-allocating space, and it may be faster to just **fetch** the content to put into that space.

In other cases, it may be plain impossible. Infinite and random iterators fall into this category, but also iterators over external resources.

> Is there a way to get the hint for zips and generators as well? Or is it something fundamental only to iterators?

If an object does not implement `__length_hint__`, then no. Zip and generators don't, probably for the efficiency reasons above.

Also note that a zip and generator objects are their own iterator.

```
foo = zip([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
id(foo) == id(iter(foo))  # returns True in py3.5
```

Answer (score 7):

> Wow! A way to get the iterator length without exhausting the iterator.

**No.** It's a way to get a **vague hint** about what the length might be. There is no requirement that it be in any way accurate.

> Is there a simple explanation how does this magic work?

The iterator implements a `__length_hint__` method that uses some sort of iterator-specific information to make a guess about how many elements it will output. This guess could be pretty decent, or it could suck horribly. For example, a list iterator knows where it is in the list and how long the list is, so it can report how many elements are left in the list.

> Are there limitations and cases where it wouldn't work?

If the iterator doesn't have enough information to guess when it will run out, it can't implement a useful `__length_hint__`. This is why generators don't have one, for example. Infinite iterators also can't implement a useful `__length_hint__`, as there is no way to signal an infinite length.

> Is there a way to get the hint for zips and generators as well? Or is it something fundamental only to iterators?

`zip` instances and generators are both kinds of iterators. Neither `zip` nor the generator type provide a `__length_hint__` method, though.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of this is basically just to facilitate more performant allocation of memory in Cython/C code. For example, imagine that a Cython module exposes a function that takes an iterable of custom `MyNetworkConnection()` objects and, internally, needs to create and allocate memory for data structures to represent them in the Cython/C code.  If we can get a rough estimate of the number of items in the iterator, we can allocate a large enough slab of memory in one operation to accommodate all of them with minimal resizing.

If `__len__()` is implemented, we know the exact length and can use that for memory allocation. But often times we won't actually know the exact length, so the estimate helps us improve performance by giving us a "ballpark figure".

It's also surely useful in pure-Python code as well, for example, maybe a user-facing completion time estimate for an operation?

For question 2, well, it's a hint, so you can't rely on it to be exact. You must still account for allocating new memory if the hint is too low, or cleaning up if the hint is too high. I'm not personally aware of other limitations or potential problems.

For question 3, I see no reason why it wouldn't work for Generators, since a Generator *is an Iterator*:

```
>>> import collections
>>> def my_generator(): yield
>>> gen = my_generator()
>>> isinstance(gen, collections.Iterator)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the hint for zips and generators as well? Or is it something fundamental only to iterators?

In the case of generator I don't think that there is a easy or automatic way of doing it, because if you give my a arbitrary generator, which I don't know how it was made, how can I determine if it is finite or not?? I would need to look at the code, and if use some other function, I need to look at those function and how they are called and... it get messy pretty quick, so for a automatic way, the effort needed look much greater than the reward

In the case of `zip`, I don't know why it don't have it, look easy enough to check for the each hint of each element and return the minimum among them, perhaps they don't add it because you can give generator to it and there is no why to get a hint from them?

So it may be a thing better in iterator because they are made with the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)

```
class MyIterator:
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        ...
        if condition_for_more_values:
            ...
            return next_value
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

so is more easy here to add the logic for the `__length_hint__` function when this make sense, and that is why the build-in container (list, tuple, str, set, etc.) have such feature because they are made something like this

```
class Container:
    ...

    def __len__(self):
        ...

    def iter(self):
        return Container_Iterator(self)

class Container_Iterator:

    def __init__(self,con):
        self.i=0
        self.data=con

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i<len(self.data):
            self.i+=1
            return self.data[self.i-1]
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

as the `Conatiner_Iterator` have access to all the relevant info of the Container it know were it is at each time so it can give a meaningful hint and it can be as simple as

```
    def __length_hint__(self):
        return len(self.data) - self.i
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simple explanation how does this magic work? I'm just
> curious.

I'm gonna show some code for experiment for future readers:

-`MyClass1` implements nothing which means [the normal over-allocation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L60) occurs.
-`MyClass2` only implements `__len__`, with correct guess.
-`MyClass3` only implements `__length_hint__`, with slightly higher guess(n + 2).
-`MyClass4` implements both. Useful to see the calling precedence.

```py
from sys import getsizeof
n = 25

class MyClass1:
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(n):
            yield i

class MyClass2:
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(n):
            yield i

    def __len__(self):
        print("__len__ in MyClass2")
        return n

class MyClass3:
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(n):
            yield i

    def __length_hint__(self):
        print("__length_hint__ in MyClass3")
        return n + 2

class MyClass4:
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(n):
            yield i

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        print("__len__ in MyClass4")
        return n

    def __length_hint__(self):
        print("__length_hint__ in MyClass4")
        return n + 2

obj1 = MyClass1()
obj2 = MyClass2()
obj3 = MyClass3()
obj4 = MyClass4()

lst1 = list(obj1)
lst2 = list(obj2)
lst3 = list(obj3)
lst4 = list(obj4)

print("obj1:", getsizeof(lst1))
print("obj2:", getsizeof(lst2))
print("obj3:", getsizeof(lst3))
print("obj4:", getsizeof(lst4))
```

output:

```
__len__ in MyClass2
__length_hint__ in MyClass3
__len__ in MyClass4
obj1: 312
obj2: 264
obj3: 280
obj4: 264
```

`n = 25` is intentionally used because in this interpreter(3.10.6), `list` over-allocates after adding the 24th item so we can see the differences clearly.

The way this hinting work is mentioned in the [Specification section of PEP 424](https://peps.python.org/pep-0424/#specification).

`obj1` is expected to be the largest among `obj2` and `obj3` because of over-allocation. `obj3` is larger than `obj2` by 16 byte which is the size of two pointers in 64-bits machines. In `obj4`, since `__len__` returns a non-negative correct integer, Python didn't even call `__length_hint__` method.

---

> Are there limitations and cases where it wouldn't work? ("hint" just
> sounds a bit suspicious)

Yes if the returned guess is far from reality. If it's too low and the iteration is still not finished it ends up using normal over-allocation behavior. If it's too high, it calculates the size based on what *would* have been the size if there is no `__length_hint__`.

---

> Is there a way to get the hint for zips and generators as well? Or is
> it something fundamental only to iterators?

For `zip` case, you can subclass it and provide your own `__length_hint__` method by delegating to the individual iterables' `__len__` or `__length_hint__` (if possible). And yes it *does* reduce the memory:

Here's a simple example:

```py
from sys import getsizeof

class Zip(zip):
    def __init__(self, *iterables, strict=False) -> None:
        self.ITs = iterables

    def __length_hint__(self):
        try:
            return min(len(it) for it in self.ITs)
        except TypeError:
            return NotImplemented

z1 = list(Zip(range(1_000_000), range(1_000_000)))
z2 = list(zip(range(1_000_000), range(1_000_000)))
print(z1 == z2)
print(getsizeof(z1)) # 8000056
print(getsizeof(z2)) # 8448728
```

Does this slow the speed? Not really:

```py
from timeit import timeit

def test_zip():
    z = zip
    return list(z(range(10_000_000), range(10_000_000)))

def test_Zip():
    z = Zip
    return list(z(range(10_000_000), range(10_000_000)))

print(timeit(test_zip, globals=globals(), number=2)) # 1.622484583999721
print(timeit(test_Zip, globals=globals(), number=2)) # 1.578525709999667
```